# Fixing multiple broken headers in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache

I'm using Apache 2.4.52 and I have two headers I'd like to fix in my apache config.  The problem is only one RequestHeader works at a time.

I can only get 'SOME-TOKEN' RequestHeader working if I comment out or remove SOME-API-KEY from the config.

Note: this problem happens using either method from the code below.  Only the SOME_API_KEY header works, in order for SOME-TOKEN header to work, I have to remove the other RequestHeader.

```
RequestHeader set SOME-API-KEY "expr=%{req:SOME_API_KEY}"
RequestHeader set SOME-TOKEN "expr=%{req:SOME_TOKEN}"
```

I've also tried this - from here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html#examples
The same problem exists, only the SOME-API-KEY RequestHeader works.  Again, if I remove SOME-API-KEY RequestHeader, SOME-TOKEN header will begin working as expected.

```
SetEnvIf ^SOME.API.KEY$ ^(.*)$ fix_some_api_key=$1
RequestHeader set SOME-API-KEY %{fix_some_api_key}e env=fix_some_api_key

SetEnvIf ^SOME.TOKEN$ ^(.*)$ fix_some_token=$1
RequestHeader set SOME-TOKEN %{fix_some_token}e env=fix_some_token
```

Additional info: This api is a separate vhost using mod_wsgi, I do have `WSGIPassAuthorization ON` set.  I've tried using one RequestHeader in the main apache config, one in the vhost config and both in the virtualhost config to no avail.

Comment: Try `add` instead of `set`. Or change `SOME-TOKEN` to something else like `XYZ-TOKEN`. Maybe a bug in Apache's parsing

Comment: I tried matching on just ".TOKEN" and "SOME.", no change, only one header works.  Also tried using 'add' on both and other combinations.  I see this same behavior in 2.4.50 and upgraded to 2.4.52 hoping it was a bug.

Comment: @DWOP let me check in my server :)

Comment: Apparently its not working on your system. Your first example works for me

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if there is some other directive somehow interfering.